# Include PHP file not doing anything

Tags: php

I have a folder with two files

```
import_books_cron.php 
book_importer.php
```

The first one looks like

```
<?php

echo 'Started';
include 'book_importer.php';
echo 'I will do sth';
import_books();
echo 'End';
?>
```

book importer looks like:

```
// This is some Wordpress stuff
if( !class_exists( 'WP_Http' ) )
    include_once( ABSPATH . WPINC. '/class-http.php' );

include ( 'functions.php' );


function import_books() {
   STUFF HERE
}
```

However, the only thing that I see on my terminal is 'Started'. 
The include statement does not seem to be working.

I have just basic knowledge of PHP. Any help?

Comment: What is the content of book_importer.php?

Comment: if that included script has a fatal parse error, your entire script will abort. turn on display_errors and error_reporting in your php.ini and try again.

Comment: @EvanCarslake: uh, what? you can include/require anywhere you want. there's no "before echo" requirement AT ALL. it's `header()` calls which have to be done before output, but that's totally independent of includes

Comment: How can I turn on error and warning flags? I added the book importer code

Comment: Maybe the question should change to: I have a Wordpress app on a GoDaddy instance. How can I execute a cron job that executes this code inside wordpress environment?

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php tag error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: may be, have some error in `book_importer.php`. check that

Answer (score 0):

remove echo statement before include

Comment: Why should the OP do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this to make sure the file is actually getting loaded. if it is not, make sure it exists and is in the current folder since you are not using a path.

```
if(!@include("book_importer.php")) 
{
   echo "Not Loaded";

} else {
          echo "Loaded";
       }
```